# context menu for sharepoint list fields

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, contextmenu, sharepoint-list

Is it possible to set context menu to any fields in a sharepoint list, similar to the one dispalyed for the title field with link and edit menu ? Also i need the previlige to configure(add/remove) the options available in the context menu.Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box option to attach the context menu to a different field, but there is a solution using powershell: http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2008/08/add-sharepoint-list-item-context-menu.html

Adding options to the context menu can be done by putting a custom action in a feature: http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/06/23/sample-editcontrolblock-customaction-for-sharepoint.aspx

There are things you can do to remove options from the context menu: http://metahat.blogspot.com/2007/01/hiding-sharepoint-2007-list-context.html
However be aware that editing the OOB javascript files is NOT supported and NOT good practice!